# Map size to more than one variable with geom_point in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any option to use two variables in parameter `size` in `ggplot` function?
E.g.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec,drat, size = cyl))+
   geom_point()
```

Obviously it works and size of points depends on `cyl` variable. But is it any option to add another `size` variable which can use `alpha` option e.g. `variable = mpg`. How to do it?

I did it just for three dots as an example in Ilustrator.
[image]

Thanks,

**Update**

Thanks to @lukeA following lines of code works:

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(qsec,drat, size = cyl)) + 
    geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(qsec,drat, size = mpg), alpha = .1, colour = "red")
```

But when I want to set the size of each variable separately, it is not possible. When there is one `size` variable normally I use `scale_size_contiunous` but with two `size` variables it doesn't work. I know that using `scale_size_continuous` two times doesn't change anything. Maybe it is not possible at all, but maybe somebody find the solution.

Comment: You mean like `ggplot() + geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(qsec,drat, size = cyl)) + geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(qsec,drat, size = mpg), alpha = .1, colour = "red") `?

Comment: @lukeA Two problems occurs: how add a legend for two variables and how to manage the size for both variables. When I have one variable I use `scale_size_continuous`.

Comment: I don't think you can. The common way would be to map different variables to different aesthetics. For example you can map `mpg` to  colour, alpha, ... This way, you also get the legend.

Comment: So it means that it is not possible at the end. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now with `ggnewscale` - allowing you to have more than one scale for any aesthetic.  The scales can be defined separately too.  Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=qsec, y=drat)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_point(aes(size=cyl), color='gray20') +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(0.2, 3)) +

  new_scale("size") +

  geom_point(aes(size=mpg), alpha=0.1, color='red') +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(5, 10))
```

[image]

You can define the ranges for each scale separately.  In this case, that's important so that you can ensure that the range of sizes mapped to `mpg` is larger than the range of sizes mapped to `cyl`.  Otherwise, both are mapped to the default range (`c(1,6)`), which means many points would not have a visible red point.